# how to set collection view cell as equal row cell for all screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i am using swift 2.o collection view. In that every thing is working fine. But when i run in different screen , the width gap between each cell are different. I need three cell in each row of collection view with 8 px gap for left,right,top,bottom for all cell in collection view. And also i need to set the cell as corner radius. i need like below image :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But when i run in 5s screen i am getting like this and for 6 screen like 2nd image :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

iphone 6 :

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

See the gap between left, right, bottom , top are not equally sapced as like my first image. i need to get like my first image.

I set the min line space for cell is 6 in storyboard. But i not able to get like my first imge.

please help me out.

my popvc.swift :

```
import UIKit

class popVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var tableData: [String] = ["RESTAURANTS", "BANKS", "COFFEE","PIZZA", "HOTELS", "TAXI", "RESTAURANTS", "BANKS","COFFEE","PIZZA", "HOTELS", "TAXI","RESTAURANTS", "BANKS", "COFFEE","PIZZA", "HOTELS", "TAXI"]
    var tableImages: [String] = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png", "img6.png", "img7.png", "img8.png", "img9.png", "img10.png", "img11.png", "img11.png", "img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png", "img6.png"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: colvwCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! colvwCell
        cell.lblCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImages[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: check your collectionview frame /constratint

Comment: frame or constraint?? for cell i haven't set constraints. for my image and label i have set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the storyboard set CollectionViews Section Inset from size inspector as Top = 8, Bottom = 8, Left = 8 and Right = 8, it should look like as

[image]

And return size for cell as

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   //If you want your cell should be square in size the return the equal height and width, and make sure you deduct the Section Inset from it.
   return CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width/3) - 16, (self.view.frame.size.width/3) - 45);
}
```

Thats it, Nothing more. You should see the result as mine:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also make sure you set the constraints appropriately.

Comment: can you post that obj c code with swift.. Because your solution worked fro above 6 screen. But for 5s screen , i am getting 2 cell per row. And i need  rectangle shape like my post first image

Comment: 1. You can convert the Obj-c code into Swift, it is of not more two lines. 2. This will work for all screen, see the updated answer. 3. If you want your cell as rectangle, then set the height as you required.

Comment: yes,  convert it, but when i change the height. it still look like square `     return CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width/3) - 10, (self.view.frame.size.width/3) - 10)`

Comment: Minus some more points and see the result, CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width/3) - 10, (self.view.frame.size.width/3) - 45)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105679/discussion-between-bharat-modi-and-user5513630).

Answer (score 3):

Create a collection view using following code:

```
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    var screenSize: CGRect!
    var screenWidth: CGFloat!
    var screenHeight: CGFloat!

 override func viewDidLoad() {


        print("select block is \(self.strBlockname)")

        screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        screenWidth = screenSize.width
        screenHeight = screenSize.height
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (screenWidth/3)-1, height: (screenWidth/3)-1)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight-65), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

 func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }





    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section):\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "circle")
        return cell
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Its Output for iPhone5s,6s and 6+ is following:

**iPhone5s**

[image]

**iPhone6s**

[image]

Comment: because i used some images around 18, and 18 label . i am new in swift. so only i have asked

Comment: put my viewdidload code in you viewdidload then check

Comment: i am getting error in this line `  collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")`

Comment: app crash "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) "

Comment: how to add image and lable with this same code?? inside each cell

Comment: just need to  let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (screenWidth/3)-1, height: (screenWidth/3)-1) on your viewdidload

Comment: can you lease update this viewdidload code alone in your answer post, its not readable

Answer (score 1):

@user5513630 Add following code in collection view.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size

// 8 - space between 3 collection cells
// 4 - 4 times gap will appear between cell.
        return CGSize(width: (size.width - 4 * 8)/3, height: 40)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

read [this](http://zappdesigntemplates.com/create-3-column-grid-view-with-uicollectionview/) tutorial. it will fulfill your requirement